# ionic app crash when loading image with imagepicker

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3, photo-gallery, crash

I am trying to load images with my ionic 3 app, using image-picker plugin.
here is the content of my package.json file :

```
{
  "name": "app name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
     "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
     "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
     "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
     "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
     "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
   },
  "dependencies": {
     "@angular/common": "5.0.3",
     "@angular/compiler": "5.0.3",
      "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.3",
      "@angular/core": "5.0.3",
      "@angular/forms": "5.0.3",
      "@angular/http": "5.0.3",
      "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.3",
      "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.3",
      "@ionic-native/base64": "^4.5.3",
      "@ionic-native/core": "4.4.0",
      "@ionic-native/image-picker": "^4.5.3",
      "@ionic-native/photo-viewer": "^4.5.3",
      "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.4.0",
      "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.4.0",
      "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
      "com-badrit-base64": "^0.2.0",
      "com-sarriaroman-photoviewer": "^1.1.16",
      "cordova-android": "^6.2.2",
      "cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.2.0",
      "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.1",
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.0.5",
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^1.1.16",
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
      "cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker": "^2.1.8",
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
      "firebase": "^4.10.1",
      "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
      "ionicons": "3.0.0",
      "rxjs": "5.5.2",
      "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
      "zone.js": "0.8.18"
   },
  "devDependencies": {
      "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.8",
      "typescript": "2.4.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
    "cordova": {
      "plugins": {
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
        "cordova-plugin-device": {},
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
        "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
        "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
        "cordova-plugin-compat": {},
        "com.synconset.imagepicker": {
    "PHOTO_LIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "We need to access to your library"
    },
    "com-badrit-base64": {},
    "com-sarriaroman-photoviewer": {}
},
"platforms": [
  "android"
]
   }
}
```

when i want to access to use the plugin for image selection, here is the code i use in a file named **publish.ts**

```
  take_pictures() {
    this.picke.requestReadPermission().then(fullfilled => {
     this.picke.getPictures({
      quality: 65,
      maximumImagesCount: 10,
      width: 500,
      height: 500,
      outputType: 1 //to convert to base64 image once selected
  }).then(data => {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      /* this.base64.encodeFile(data[i]).then(d=>{
         alert(d)
         this.annonce.photo.push(d)
       }) */
      /*.then(res=>{*/
      // this.annonce.photo.push(this.getBase64Image(data[i]));
      /*  alert(res)
      })*/
      this.annonce.photo.push(("data:image/png;base64," + data[i]));
      //alert(data[i]);
    }
  }).catch(e => {

    this.toast.create({
      message: e.message,
      showCloseButton: true,
      closeButtonText: "Okay",
      dismissOnPageChange: true,
      duration: 30000
    }).present()
  })
}, rejected => {
    this.alert.create({
      message : "Please you have to select at least one picture",
      buttons :[{
        text : "Ok",
        role:"cancel"
      }]
    }).present();
})

}
```

This other method use the **photoviewer** plugin to make sure that when the user click on a picture, he can see it in a larger format :

```
see_photo(imag) {

    this.viewer.show(imag);

}
```

To display images, i use a a file named **publish.html**. here is a code snippet of it.

```
    <ion-item no-lines>
      <p align="center">Pictures</p>
    </ion-item>

    <button ion-item color="primary" block (click)="take_pictures()">
      take pictures
    </button>

    <ion-list>
      <ion-card *ngFor="let imag of this.annonce.photo">
        <img [src]="imag" (click)="see_photo(imag)" />

        <button (click)="del_photo(imag)" ion-button 
   color="primary">Supprimer</button>
      </ion-card>
    </ion-list>
```

When images are selected, application crash. But if i select for exemple only one inage everythings works fine. But with moere than one image either application become very slow, or it crashes.

any help ?

Comment: and the error is?

Comment: @Kurusu When images are selected, application crash.but if i select for exemple only one inage everythings works fine. But with moere than one image either application become very slow, or it crashes.

Comment: add your logs as well. If possible, create a fiddler/codepen etc of your code

Comment: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/index.html#module_Camera.DestinationType

I think you might have a memory problem, like written in this doc. I know this is not for the Image Picker (it is for the Camera plugin), but the problem will be the same : base64 encoded images can be very memory intensive and cause app crashes or out of memory errors. Use FILEURI or NATIVE_URI if possible

Answer (score 0):

in /platforms/android/project.properties remove all other com.android.support:support and com.android.support:appcompat and leave the latest ones. as:

```
cordova.system.library.9=com.android.support:support-v13:26.+
cordova.system.library.7=com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+
```

I have change this line:

```
cordova.system.library.1=com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23+
```

to:

```
cordova.system.library.1=com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27+
```